# Innerjoin results in empty tibble in R

Tags: r, inner-join, tibble

I have two tibbles (spain and canada) with equivalent keys and I'm trying to join them by 'Country'. Here's what they look like:

```
Country stratum  oecd schoolID studentID booklet     q   q_1   q_2   q_3   q_4   
                                                                             q_5   q_6   q_7   q_8   q_9
<chr>   <chr>   <int> <chr>    <chr>       <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> 
                                                              <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1 ESP     ESP1633     1 0000001  00005           5    NA     0    NA     1     0     0     1     0     0    NA
 2 ESP     ESP1633     1 0000001  00014           5    NA     0    NA     1     1     1     2     0     1    NA
 3 ESP     ESP0306     1 0000002  00040           5    NA     0    NA     1     0     1     2     0     1    NA
 4 ESP     ESP0306     1 0000002  00041           5    NA     0    NA     1     0     1     2     0     1    NA
 5 ESP     ESP1633     1 0000003  00062           5    NA     0    NA     0     1     1     2     0     0    NA
 6 ESP     ESP1427     1 0000004  00102           5    NA     0    NA     0

Country stratum  oecd schoolID studentID booklet     q   q_1   q_2   q_3   q_4   
q_5   q_6   q_7   q_8   q_9
   <chr>   <chr>   <int> <chr>    <chr>       <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> 
<int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1 CAN     CAN0762     1 0000001  00014           5    NA     0    NA     1     1     1     2     1     1    NA
 2 CAN     CAN0762     1 0000001  00020           5    NA     0    NA     1     1     1     2     1     0    NA
 3 CAN     CAN0542     1 0000002  00039           5    NA     0    NA     1     0     1     2     1     1    NA
 4 CAN     CAN0652     1 0000003  00061           5    NA     0    NA     1     1     1     2     0     1    NA
 5 CAN     CAN0652     1 0000003  00063           5    NA     0    NA     1     0     1     2     2     1    NA
 6 CAN     CAN0652     1 0000004  00078           5    NA     0    NA     0     0     1     1     0     1    NA
```

When I try either

```
combo<-inner_join(spain,canada,by='Country')
```

or

```
spain%<%
innerjoin(canda,by='Country')
```

the result I get is

```
A tibble: 0 x 227
# ... with 227 variables: Country <chr>, stratum.x <chr>, oecd.x <int>,
```

Please help! My intuition is that the tibble should be around 3500 rows (the total values for spain+canada) I want to get it so that all the value for spain and canada are in one tibble so that I can eventually perform a differential item functioning (DIF) analysis. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should use a  `full_join` as the countries are different and thus there are no overlabs and therefore nothing in the `inner_join`

Comment: Your inner join asks for the rows where country='spain' & country='canada'. There are no such rows since 'spain'<>'canada'. You seem to want the rows where country='spain' union the rows where country='canada', that is the rows where country='spain' or country='canada'. That is also the relational union of the select/restrict of rows where country='spain' union the select/restrict of rows where  country='canada'. It is also the inner join on country='spain' or country='canada'. Full join is inner join rows union unmatched rows extended by nulls so you can use full join on false for the union.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to combine the two tibbles into one and they have the same columns you want to use

```
combo <- rbind(spain, canada)
```

or

```
library(dplyr)
combo <- bind_rows(spain, canada)
```